# Checking if string contains number and symbol

Tags: javascript, html, ezpublish

I am working on an account creation site for a college.

My problem is that I want to return error messages if the password the user is setting doesn't contain numbers and/or symbols, and I need help.

The password needs to contain higher and lower case letters, a number and a symbol (!, #, % or &). I need the error messages to be specific.

Any suggestions? I am using HTML and JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using Regex and running a check on each

Like so:

```
function validateStr(str) {
    var regex = new RegExp("[A-Z]+"); // Check for uppercase first   
    if(regex.test(str) == true) {
        regex = new RegExp("[0-9]+"); // Now we check for numbers   
        if(regex.test(str) == true) {
            regex = new RegExp("[a-z]+"); // checking now for lowercase
            if(regex.test(str) == true) {
                return 1;   
            } else return 2;
        } else return 3;
    } else return 4;
}
```

I haven't included the "Special Character" parameter because you have to include those individually in to one regular expression which I don't recommend you do.
I am struggling to get it to work on JSFiddle so I haven't included one but just post a comment if you need me to explain further.

Comment: I did it so that you can use it to specify specific error text to the user if you wanted.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. I can fiddle around a bit and see if I can include the special character edits myself.

Answer (score 1):

Although the solution based on JS and regexp is a good start (and faster because executed on the client side), I would recommend to double-check this server side.

Since I see that you are probably using eZ Publish (based on this question's tags...), feel free to override the eZUser class (with the eZ Publish autoload system or with PHP include path magic), then hack the eZUser::validatePassword() method to fulfill your requirements.